# Azure data factory Lookup

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a lookup activity which reads data from a SQL table and the output of this is passed onto multiple Execute Pipeline tasks as parameters. The flow is as follows

> Lookup -> Exct Pipeline 1 -> Exct Pipeline 2 -> Exct Pipeline 3

.This works fine for the first pipeline however the second execute Pipeline fails with the following error.

```
> "The template validation failed: 'The inputs of template action 'Exct
> Pipeline 2' at line '1 and column '178987' cannot reference action
> 'Lookup'. Action 'Lookup' must either be in 'runAfter' path or within
> a scope action on the 'runAfter' path of action 'Execute Pipeline 3',
> or be a Trigger"
```

Another point to be noted is that the Pipeline runs fine when triggered.It only fails when in debug.
Has anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: This looks like some issue with the JSON code of the pipeline. I recreated the pipeline and it works fine. On comparing the codes, I could see differences in the order of the activities which I think caused the issue.

Comment: You could summarize your solution as an answer for others'  reference.